# Simulate 2 people tossing coin until get first head Python

Tags: python, probability

So I have `A` and `B` play a game which begins with `A` tossing a coin. If it shows head, `A` wins and game over. Else, `B` tosses and if `B` gets a head, `B` wins and game over. Basically, the game continues until whoever's coin shows a head first.

Theoretically, the probability of `A` winning is `2/3`, and the probability of `B` winning is `1/3`. Referenced [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94331/two-players-alternately-flip-a-coin-what-is-the-probability-of-winning-by-getti)

I'm trying to simulate this in `Python`, running `4000` simulations. However, I'm not really getting close to `2/3` for `A` and `1/3` for `B`. Below is my code:

```
import random

Atoss = 0
Btoss = 0

Awins = []
Bwins = []

for i in range(4001):
   head = False
   while (not head):
      A = random.randint(0, 2)  # random 0 and 1
      Atoss += 1

      if A == 1:
         head = True
      else:
         B = random.randint(0, 2)  # random 0 and 1
         Btoss += 1
         if B == 1:
            head = True

   totalToss = Atoss + Btoss
   Awin = Atoss / totalToss
   Awins.append(Awin)
   Bwin = Btoss / totalToss
   Bwins.append(Bwin)

probA = sum(Awins) / len(Awins)
probB = sum(Bwins) / len(Bwins)

print("Probability A: ", probA)
print("Probability B: ", probB)
```

Did I mess up somewhere?

**EDIT:**

Changing `randint(0, 2)` to `randint(0, 1)` solves the problem, as answered by @bart cubrich

Comment: Your `Awin`/`Bwin`/`Awins`/`Bwins` computations don't look anything like how victory in the game is defined.

Comment: yeah I thought that doing # of tosses / total tosses is not right, but I couldn't figure out how to "code" it like I had it on paper

Comment: The main error is this code is a typo, so maybe deserves a downvote, but it's a cool problem, and generally I liked your solution. Plus you were upfront with that fact that it could just be a mistake. Definitely don't need to keep track of the number of tosses, but it's interesting to see how many more tosses are needed that for loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem you have is that the random.randomint should be

```
A = random.randint(0, 1)  # random 0 and 1
B = random.randint(0, 1)  # random 0 and 1
```

Your version was producing zeros, ones, and twos. That was totally messing up the chances of getting a heads, since you were really rolling a 3 sided die with sides=[0,1,2], where only a "1" wins. Trying the following:

```
import random
random.seed(123)
Atoss = 0
Btoss = 0

Awins = 0
Bwins = 0

for i in range(4000):
   head = False
   while (not head):
      A = random.randint(0, 1)  # random 0 and 1

      if A == 1:
         Awins+=1
         head = True

      else:
         B = random.randint(0, 1)  # random 0 and 1
         if B == 1:
            Bwins+=1
            head = True



probA = Awins / (Awins+Bwins)
probB = Bwins / (Awins+Bwins)

print("Probability A: ", probA)
print("Probability B: ", probB)

Out:
'Probability A:  0.6653336665833541'
'Probability B:  0.3346663334166458'
```

I get that the probability is ~A:66% B:33%.

Note, in the documentation from random.py

**random.randint(a, b)**
-Return a random integer N such that a <= N <= b.

which is different than the numpy.random.randomint which gives

-a random integer N such that a <= N < b

[Documentation is here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback, answers, plus not downvoting me :) 

About me writing `randint(0,2)`, it was actually intentional, because I thought the way `randint(a, b)` works is that it would give you random numbers in the range `a` to `b - 1`, so I put the `2` there. Apparently I was wrong.
But thank you so much anyway!

Comment: Yeah, remember to use simple steps when debugging. I tried to run your game with different rules. I ran the case where if A doesn't flip heads B wins. That should have had 50/50 odds, but didn't, and that's when I saw the problem with random.randint(0,2). Also, when using new libraries and methods be sure to read the documentation. Also, you had range(4001) when it should have been range(4000), so be sure to learn how range works. I like to use and IDE like anaconda/spyder so I can easily look inside of variables. Confusingly, numpys' random.randomint() works like you though.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Awin` and `Bwin` computations say that if A wins on the 5th toss, then since A tossed 3 times and B tossed 2 times, A gets 3/5 of a win and B gets 2/5. This is not how victory is supposed to work.

Also, you want `random.randrange`, not `random.randint`, and your placement of the `Atoss` and `Btoss` initialization before the loop instead of inside the loop means they don't reset on a new iteration. (The toss counts are unnecessary in a correct implementation, though.)

Comment: Right I did feel like getting the win probability is super easy but I can't wrap my head around it, and doing # of toss / total toss didn't seem right.
Can you give me some guidance here?